# PHP/Sqlite3 process synchronization

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm new to PHP and I've been tasked with writing a simple script that is backed by a Sqlite3 DB.  The script is complete and working, but I'm trying to figure out how to handle process synchronization.

Since Sqlite3 is not a typical server DB model, each process that accesses the DB opens the file.  So if simultaneous requests come in to my PHP script, each would try and open the DB file.  Thus I'm assuming I need some sort of synchronization here.

My initial thought was semaphores.  However, the following code always fails on sem_acquire:

```
if($semaphone = sem_get(112233))
{
    if(sem_acquire($semaphore))
    {
        if($db = new SQLite3("mydb.sqlite"))
        {
            ...
            $db->close();
        }

        flock($lock, LOCK_UN);
    }
}
```

Since I'm new to PHP I don't know how to figure out why sem_acquire is failing.  I suspect my PHP might not be compiled with system V resources.

Next I decided to try flock.  I tried the following code, but it doesn't work.  When I try and access my PHP script I get back nothing (it's as if my script doesn't run, or perhaps it crashes):

```
if($lock = fopen("abc123", "w+"))
{
    if(flock($lock, LOCK_EX))
    {
        if($db = new SQLite3("mydb.sqlite"))
        {
            ...
            $db->close();
        }

        flock($lock, LOCK_UN);
    }
}
```

Please, can anyone tell me how to synchronize this, or if synchronization is even necessary?

BTW, I'm running this is all running on Ubuntu 12.04 w/ nginx and php5-fpm.

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother, SQLite clients and drivers [handle concurrency natively](http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html).